# Java get UserName from UserList and setItems ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have this:

```
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> choiseData;

ObservableList<String> choiseUserList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<User> userList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();    
AdminSQL sql = new AdminSQL();
userList = sql.getAllUser();

for (User u : userList)
choiseUserList.add(u.getUserLogin());
choiseData.setItems(choiseUserList);
```

I do not like the two list and the loop. I wonder if you can only download users' logins directly from the userList list and place them ChoiseBox

Class User:

```
private IntegerProperty userLp;
private StringProperty userLogin;
private StringProperty userRule;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "two letters"? The two `ObservableList`?

Comment: my mistake. I mean "i dont like two list" :)

Comment: `ComboBox`(title) or `ChoiceBox`(question text+code) or *"doesn't matter"*?

Comment: It's not for me. The idea of completing the list is identical

Comment: don't understand the problem: you have the list of users and should set that list as items of the choicebox - why the second list?

Comment: Yes, why not just use a `ChoiceBox<User>` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you *don't want* to have the ChoiceBox items as a list that's mapped once (somehow) from the real items because doing so comes with a handful of disadvantages:

- the two lists can get easily out off sync: when the users change or any its properties, the ChoiceBox is not updated
- when listening to f.i. selection changes in the ChoiceBox, the listener doesn't have the complete information about the user (from the selectedItem) but just one of its property values - if it wants to act on the user, it would have to look it up the info somewhere else, thus introducing (unwanted) coupling
- you are fighting the winds of fx, which has dedicated support to configure visual representations of any data object - in the case of a ChoiceBox you'd need a StringConverter

Example code snippet:

```
ChoiceBox<User> choiceBox =  new ChoiceBox<>(getUsers()); 
    // from your snippet, AdminSQL already returns the list as
    // an ObservableList, so you can set it directly as provided
    // new ChoiceBox<>(sql.getAllUsers()); 
StringConverter<User> converter = new StringConverter<>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(User user) {
        return user != null ? user.getUserLogin() : "";
    }

    @Override
    public User fromString(String userLogin) {
        // should never happen, choicebox is not editable
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("back conversion not supported from " + userLogin);
    }

};
choiceBox.setConverter(converter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8 Streams**

```
choiseData.getItems().addAll(userList.stream().map(User::getUserLogin()));
```

Comment: technically correct but not what you'd do in fx ;) Instead of having a separate list of names (vs User) as items, you would configure the ChoiceBox with a converter that uses the name of a user to show the item

Comment: Who use ComboBox or ChoiseBox if you have in DataBase user data login, password, lp etc. You have use sql ok! But if you have already method getAllUserData why write another sql method ? Of course I can do if in sql method. There are many roads and I just learned streamers for which I thank you :)

Comment: Exactly as you write. I see some restrictions when I download data from the choisebox. I do not use only the string on the object anymore. I have unique logins in the database, so in this case it's not a problem, but in the future it can be a challenge.

Comment: @Light in the context of fx this is wrong (the ui is independent of how to get the data) - the sooner you learn how to use fx controls correctly, the better ..

Comment: @NikiforosArchakis exactly, ChoiceBox<User> is the correct (and the only acceptable) fx option :)

Comment: dont mix comments please - that's creating fake news <g> No: with ChoiceBox<User> the selected item is-a User with all its properties that can be directly accessed f.i. in any listener to the selection - with ChoiceBox<String> a listener has just the name (or whatever) with which it needs to lookup the user somewhere to access any of the other properties. The latter is more coupled to its surrounding than the former.